# Python change the scope of classes dynamically created with type() function

Tags: python, class, scope, dynamic-class-creation

I have a factory class with a method that generates classes dynamically.
This class is within a `factory.py` file.

```py
class Factory:
    def __init__(self, ast):
        self.ast = ast
        self.classes = {}
    
    def run(self):
        for item in self.ast:
            self.classes[item.name] = type(item.classname, (), item.attributes)
```

Quite simple. The problem is that the generated classes are prefixed with `factory.` e.g.
`<class 'factory.MyClass'>` or `<class 'factory.AnotherClass'>`.

I would like to be able to change the scope in which these classes are defined, for instance to something like that :

```
<class 'CustomClasses.MyClass'>
```

But it seems that the prefix depends on the module in which the `type()` function is called. Is there any way to change this behavior ?

Comment: Why is what the `type` function returns a problem? If you want to check the `type()` of an instance of `Factory`, then after `from factory import Factory` and `f = Factory()`, `type(f) == Factory` is `True`. If this isn't your problem, then what is it?

Comment: The class name itself does not include `factory`. That's an artifact of how `type.__repr__` is defined. (Even if it did, the name of the class typically doesn't matter *except* for how `__repr__` renders it. It's not related to any variables referring to the class.)

Comment: Ideally I wish I could have all the classes as attributes of the `CustomClasses` module and make them accessible this way rather than storing them in the local dictionnary.

Comment: Why don't you just do that, then? `setattr(CustomClass, item.name) = type(item.classname, (), item.attributes)`